What do the words "descends" and "Induced" mean in the following quoted passage?
The following is taken from pg 4 section 6.1 of the following notes
Background

$\quad$ We start by observing that a ring homomorphism descends to quotient rings whenever the image of an ideal on the source is contained in the an ideal on the target.
Induced map Lemma 6.1.0.  Let $\varphi:R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism.  For any ideal $I$ in the ring $R$ and any ideal $J$ in the ring $S$ satisfying $\varphi(I)\subseteq J$, the induced map $\bar{\varphi}:R/I\to S/J$, defined for any ring element $r$ in $R$ by $\bar{\varphi}(r+I)=\varphi(r)+J$, is a well-defined ring homomorphism.

Below is a screenshot of the cited passage above.

Questions
I have a quick question.  In the quoted passage above, what do the two words descends and Induced mean?  I have seen the first word used in algebra, while the later, i have often seen it in the context of both algebra and topology.
Thank you in advance

We usually view a ring $R$ as being "above" the quotient $R/I$, so we view this homomorphism as "descending" to the quotient. As for "induced", it means that the ring homomorphism gives rise to a homomorphism of quotients. See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/induced

@ljfirth by "above", is that a metaphorical way of meaning something?  Also, how does it relate to "Induced", and in what sense?  I am getting a some action is being taken.  I don't mean in the sense of group actions.

"Above" just relates to this picture we have in our head as a way to imagine these rings. The ring homomorphism "upstairs" gives you a quotient homomorphism "downstairs", given by the formula in the text. This is what we mean by "induced".

@ljfirth the word "induced" is used in this context is not the same as in the case of topology where you often hear something "induces" anothber map, usually a homeomorphsim?  Also is another equivalent term to "induced" is to create/generate?

Yes, in a way that’s what it means.

@ljfirth thank you for your explanation.  :)
